# Default settings Raspberry Pi /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have changed the settings of `/etc/network/interfaces` but with this action my internet doesn't work anymore.

Now I want to change it back but I can't find the default settings.

If you have the default setting, can you place them here please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are the default settings I have for /etc/network/interfaces (including WiFi settings) for my Raspberry Pi 1:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 22):

For my Raspberry Pi 3B model it was

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have a DHCP server running at your router I would use:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

After changing the file issue (as root):

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Do you also know what settings I need for wifi?

Comment: This depends on your wifi setup and what type of wifi stick you are using. Would fit for another question

Comment: Somebody downvoted this without leaving a reason. If you would tell me the reasons I could help with the problem and/or enhance the post to fit your needs.